# Lista Simplesmente Encadeada - eliminar a primeira metade da lista

Tags: c, lista, lista-encadeada

Boa tarde, pessoal.
Espero que eu esteja publicando de forma certa, porque sou novo no fórum e novo na programação.
Então, sobre uma dúvida que estou, mais especificamente em "Listas Encadeadas Simples", é que a função abaixo deve eliminar a primeira metade da lista encadeada.
Eu teria que percorrer toda lista para eliminar a metade da lista, caso seja par.

Será que estou fazendo de forma certa?

Se puderem me ajudar com o código abaixo, será muito bem-vindo!!

Função abaixo:

```
// (c) Remove a primeira metade da Lista. Caso a lista possua um número ímpar de elementos,
// considere que a primeira metade possui mais elementos
// (Ex: se a lista possuir 5 elementos, a primeira metade possui os 3 primeiros elementos).
// Se a lista tiver vazia, nada acontece.
void removePrimeiraMetade(Lista *L) {
    // IMPLEMENTE ESTA FUNÇÃO
    //Estou pensando no código
    if (listaEstavazia(L)){
      return;
    }
    else{
      No *p = L->inicio;
      No *anterior = NULL;
      while (p != NULL){
        if (L->tamanho % 2 == 0){
          anterior->prox = no->prox;
          L->tamanho--;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Struct `_no`, `_produto` e `_lista` (não tá na ordem, mas está aqui):

```
typedef struct _produto {
    int num_serie; // numero de série do produto
    char nome[64];
    double preço;
} Produto;

// struct que define um nó curcular duplamente encadeado
typedef struct _no {
    Produto *prod;
    struct _no *prox;
} No;

// struct que define uma Lista Ligada Simples
typedef struct _lista {
    No *inicio;
    No *fim;
    int tamanho; // numero de nós da lista
} Lista;
```

Atualização do código acima:

O código ficou basicamente assim, né?

```
if (listaEstaVazia(L)){
    return;
}
else {
    int tamanho = L->tamanho;
    if (tamanho % 2 == 0){
        for (int i=0; i<(tamanho / 2); i++){
            L->inicio = L->inicio->prox;
            L->tamanho--;
        }
    }
    else {
        double impar = round(L->tamanho / 2);
        for (int i=0; i<impar; i++){
            L->inicio = L->inicio->prox;
            L->tamanho--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pegue o tamanho da lista e divida por 2, chame esse valor de _loops_. Depois rode um for que vai até a quantidade de _loops_, para cada ciclo você remove o primeiro item da lista.

Comment: E se o tamanho da lista for ímpar? Por exemplo, eu tenho uma lista de tamanho 5, a "metade" é 3, e devo pegá-los. É basicamente smeelhante quando faço em lista par.

Comment: Nesse caso, você decide se arredonda para cima ou para baixo. Se estiver usando uma variável do tipo **int**, ela irá ignorar as casas decimais, o que dá o efeito de "arredondar para baixo".

Comment: Entendi. Nesse caso, então, devo declarar uma nova variável do tipo float?

Comment: Pode simplesmente dividir o `L->tamanho` por 2, fazer um `for loop` que percorra todos os nós desde o L->inicio até ao nó em questão, apagando-os e trocando depois o L->inicio pelo nó final

Answer (score 0):

> // (c) Remove a primeira metade da Lista. Caso a lista possua um número ímpar de elementos,
> // considere que a primeira metade possui mais elementos
> // (Ex: se a lista possuir 5 elementos, a primeira metade possui os 3 primeiros elementos).
> // Se a lista tiver vazia, nada acontece.

#### Preste atenção aos dados...

Não precisa fazer nada disso de módulo e contar se é par e tal.

Entenda que:

- se a lista está vazia não vai fazer nada
- se a lista só tem um cara então não tem metade e não vai fazer nada
- a partir daí vai apagar ao menos um: então:
- apague 1
- apague metade dos outros

**Exemplos:**

- se eram 2: vai apagar um e resta 1/2 = 0: apaga 1, ok
- se eram 3: apaga um e resta 2/2 = 1: apaga 2, ok
- se eram 4: apaga um e restam 3/2 = 1: apaga 2, ok
- se eram 5, o exemplo: apaga 1, restam 4/2 = 2: apaga 3, ok

Não precisa testar nada mais.

#### poste um programa completo que se possa compilar

> Eu teria que percorrer toda lista para eliminar a metade da lista,
> caso seja par

E porque? Apenas defina quantos vai remover, como eu disse. Se posicione no início e apague o primeiro e depois metade dos outros num loop. A divisão por inteiro, como sabe, vai truncar os valores.